# Android - How to retrieve contacts list as in native app?

Tags: java, android, contacts

I'm looking to export the contacts that are stored in the native database.
I'm having trouble retrieving contacts from native database.

Here is the query I would like to use :

> Get all the contacts that have at least a phone number or an email.

Here is the query I am using :

```
String dataWhere = ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=? OR " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?";
String[] dataWhereValues = new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
String[] dataProjection = new String[]{ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID, ContactsContract.Data.LOOKUP_KEY, ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY, ContactsContract.Data.STARRED, ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.Data.DATA1, ContactsContract.Data.DATA2, ContactsContract.Data.DATA_VERSION};
Cursor data = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, dataProjection, dataWhere, dataWhereValues, ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID);
```

But this query gives me lots of weird contacts, and some of my contacts are also missing...

Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: Hello Harry . did you find any solution to get contact .?

Comment: Hello AndroEmbedded, please look at the solution I ended up with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the query I ended up with

```
String where = ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=? OR " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?";
String[] whereValues = new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};

String[] dataProjection = new String[]{ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID, ContactsContract.Data.LOOKUP_KEY, ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY, ContactsContract.Data.STARRED, ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.Data.DATA1, ContactsContract.Data.DATA2, ContactsContract.Data.DATA_VERSION};
Cursor cursor =  context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, dataProjection, dataWhere, dataWhereValues, ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " ASC");

int cidIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID);
int nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY);
int starredIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Data.STARRED);
int typeIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE);
int data1Index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Data.DATA1);
int data2Index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Data.DATA2);
int lookupKeyIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Data.LOOKUP_KEY);
int versionIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Data.DATA_VERSION);
boolean hasData = cursor.moveToNext();

while (hasData){
    contactId = cursor.getLong(cidIndex);
    nativeLookupKey = cursor.getString(lookupKeyIndex);
    fullName = cursor.getString(nameIndex);
    starred = cursor.getInt(starredIndex);
    version = cursor.getLong(versionIndex);

    while (currentContactId <= contactId && hasData) {
        if (currentContactId == contactId) {
            String type = cursor.getString(typeIndex);
            if (type.equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)) {
                String email = cursor.getString(data1Index);                      
            } else if (type.equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)) {
                String number = cursor.getString(data1Index);
            }
        }

        hasData = cursor.moveToNext();
        if (hasData) {
            currentContactId = cursor.getLong(cidIndex);
        }  
    }            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this may help you for getting phone numbers and display names...

```
 Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,         null,null,null, null);
        // importing phone contacts 
         while (phones.moveToNext())
         {

               listMobileNo.add(phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));
            listName.add(phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME)));

         }
         phones.close();
```

Comment: Thx, but it does not answer my question. I need the entire query to be processed in one time.